# OperationalError at / no such column: core_book.average_rating

Tags: python, django

So When I go to my home page route I get OperationalError at /
no such column: core_book.average_rating even though I don't think home view mentions that average_rating column in a model. If you want to see the full code it is at `https://github.com/ArpitLinux/HostingCode/blob/main/code.txt`, Sorry but I cannot put home.html here because of character limit So please consider seeing my github link if you want to see home.html

views.py

```
def home(request):
    category = Category.objects.all()
    carosel1 = CarouselDisplay1.objects.order_by('-id')[:1]
    carosel2 = CarouselDisplay2.objects.order_by('-id')[:1]
    carosel3 = CarouselDisplay3.objects.order_by('-id')[:1]
    engineering_book = Category.objects.get(name="Engineering")
    programming_book = Category.objects.get(name="Programming")
    neuroscience_book = Category.objects.get(name="Neuroscience")
    physics_book = Category.objects.get(name="Physics")
    medical_book = Category.objects.get(name="Medical")
    rocket_book = Category.objects.get(name="Rocket Science")
    engineering_books1 = Book.objects.filter(category=engineering_book.id)[:3]
    engineering_books2 = Book.objects.filter(category=engineering_book.id)[3:6]
    engineering_books3 = Book.objects.filter(category=engineering_book.id)[6:9]
    programming_books1 = Book.objects.filter(category=programming_book.id)[:3]
    programming_books2 = Book.objects.filter(category=programming_book.id)[3:6]
    programming_books3 = Book.objects.filter(category=programming_book.id)[6:9]
    neuroscience_books1 = Book.objects.filter(category=neuroscience_book.id)[:3]
    neuroscience_books2 = Book.objects.filter(category=neuroscience_book.id)[3:6]
    neuroscience_books3 = Book.objects.filter(category=neuroscience_book.id)[6:9]
    physics_books1 = Book.objects.filter(category=physics_book.id)[:3]
    physics_books2 = Book.objects.filter(category=physics_book.id)[3:6]
    physics_books3 = Book.objects.filter(category=physics_book.id)[6:9]
    medical_books1 = Book.objects.filter(category=medical_book.id)[:3]
    medical_books2 = Book.objects.filter(category=medical_book.id)[3:6]
    medical_books3 = Book.objects.filter(category=medical_book.id)[6:9]
    rocket_books1 = Book.objects.filter(category=rocket_book.id)[:3]
    rocket_books2 = Book.objects.filter(category=rocket_book.id)[3:6]
    rocket_books3 = Book.objects.filter(category=rocket_book.id)[6:9]
    params = {'carosel1':carosel1, 'carosel2':carosel2, 'carosel3':carosel3, 'engineering_books1':engineering_books1,
    'engineering_books2':engineering_books2, 'engineering_books3':engineering_books3, 'programming_books1':programming_books1,
    'programming_books2':programming_books2, 'programming_books3':programming_books3, 'neuroscience_books1':neuroscience_books1,
    'neuroscience_books2':neuroscience_books2, 'neuroscience_books3':neuroscience_books3, 'physics_books1':physics_books1,
    'physics_books2':physics_books2, 'physics_books3':physics_books3, 'medical_books1':medical_books1,
    'medical_books2':medical_books2, 'medical_books3':medical_books3, 'rocket_books1':rocket_books1,
    'rocket_books2':rocket_books2, 'rocket_books3':rocket_books3, 'category':category
    }
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        oof = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('book', flat=True)
        lmao = OrderItem.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('book', flat=True)
        hehe = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        number = 0
        fianlprice = 0
        for item in hehe:
            fianlprice += item.book.price
        for num in hehe:
            number += 1
        books = Book.objects.all()
        true_params = {'price':fianlprice, 'error':'', 'cart':oof, 'order':lmao, 'number':number, 'items':hehe,'carosel1':carosel1, 'carosel2':carosel2, 'carosel3':carosel3, 'engineering_books1':engineering_books1,
    'engineering_books2':engineering_books2, 'engineering_books3':engineering_books3, 'programming_books1':programming_books1,
    'programming_books2':programming_books2, 'programming_books3':programming_books3, 'neuroscience_books1':neuroscience_books1,
    'neuroscience_books2':neuroscience_books2, 'neuroscience_books3':neuroscience_books3, 'physics_books1':physics_books1,
    'physics_books2':physics_books2, 'physics_books3':physics_books3, 'medical_books1':medical_books1,
    'medical_books2':medical_books2, 'medical_books3':medical_books3, 'rocket_books1':rocket_books1,
    'rocket_books2':rocket_books2, 'rocket_books3':rocket_books3, 'category':category}
        return render(request, 'main/home.html', true_params)
    else:
        books = Book.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'main/home.html', params)
```

Comment: Did you add the app to the setting and create and apply the migration?

Comment: Yes, That seems to fix the issue, Thank you so much